# Uniques fields in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a field unique in MongoDB Atlas but I don't understand how to make it.

[image: 1]

Here I have my data, that I post with an NodeJS API Rest. How can I make the field "ID" unique?

I know that `MongoDB Atlas` adds 2 fields more, `_id` and `_ _v`, but I need `ID` to be unique, so when I do a `POST`  in the API, I avoid having repetead data.

Comment: Have you checked out [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/)?

Comment: Yes, but where I have to write `db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )` ?

Comment: learn about the basics like [mongo shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/query/sql/shell/connect/) first.

Comment: There should be basic indexing capability with whatever you are using to insert documents.

Answer (score 0):

I only added `unique` to `Mongoose Schema`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "id": {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    "email": {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    "first_name":{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "last_name":{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "company":{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "url":{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    "text":{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }     
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```